# How to store ViewData in TempData when not using Sessions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, tempdata

I recently learned that TempData for MVC is backed by Sessions by default, which is a terrible idea if one ever intends to have a web farm...

I attempted to implement Brock Allen's [Cookie based TempData provider](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/), however, The ViewData object itself is not marked Seriablizable, and as such, cannot be stored in the Cookie Based provider (or Session State Service, etc etc...)

```
Type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary' in Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

BrockAllen.CookieTempData.CookieTempDataProvider.SaveTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 values) in c:\ballen\github\CookieTempData\45\BrockAllen.CookieTempData\CookieTempDataProvider.cs:31

System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Save(ControllerContext controllerContext, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider) +154
```

How do I get around this?!

**Update:**

Perhaps a batter way to ask this would be: how do I send ViewData to another Controller method (PRG: Post, Redirect, Get paradigm) WITHOUT needing TempData (and therefore Sessions)?

Comment: Have you considered using farm-friendly session providers (like SqlServer or ASP.NET Session State Server)?

Comment: ViewData in MVC, correct.  No, I haven't considered using any farm-friendly providers, I'm trying to remove Session dependency completely, and I thought I had until I learned that TempData uses Sessions explicitly...  Even Session State Service would require the objects to be serializable :(

Comment: It says in your header `viewState`. Which obviously don't belong to MVC. `App Fabric` is great idea when you have a web farm

Comment: I apologize, fixing title...

Comment: If you want to share some state (using cookies, state server or anything else) between machines, state need to be serializable

Comment: I agree, however, ViewDataDictionary is not serializable...  `Type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary' in Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.`